# Unable to get ViewPager to fill the screen width with a relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

The view seems to be able to fill the screen vertically but not horizontally.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you no other child layout inside RelativeLayout just make ViewPager as Parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set that many attributes, you can use:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I ended up just removing the RelativeLayout so the ViewPager would take up the entire layout. Thanks though!